# Kubernetes secret getting corrupted

Tags: oracle, jenkins-groovy, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to create a secret with a file of type Oracle wallet - cwallet.sso file. But I noticed that, the checksum of the mounted file is not same as the original file. 
As a result, I am unable to connect to db.

I am trying to create secret from the file itself as below:
kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} create secret generic conn-details --from-file=./sqlnet.ora --from-file=./tnsnames.ora --from-file=./cwallet.sso -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -

Is there something wrong with my approach?

Adding more details that I had missed earlier:
The secret creation works manually, but via Jenkins pipeline it fails. 
Is the below syntax a correct way to copy sso file type?
`writeFile file: "cwallet.sso", text: libraryResource('adw' + '/cwallet.sso')`

Comment: did you notice any changes in the mounted file? are both identical?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't reproduce the issue.

`root@app:/app# md5sum cwallet.sso sqlnet.ora tnsnames.ora `
`693c9858cf3ffadec26cc67a224b3a97  cwallet.sso`
`7a5043aba4492d8e163a192f2597d753  sqlnet.ora`
`1804d67d3a802c2371ede9607b7bacec  tnsnames.ora`



`$ md5sum cwallet.sso sqlnet.ora tnsnames.ora`
`693c9858cf3ffadec26cc67a224b3a97  cwallet.sso`
`7a5043aba4492d8e163a192f2597d753  sqlnet.ora`
`1804d67d3a802c2371ede9607b7bacec  tnsnames.ora`

could you please share more details if possible?

Comment: How was the cwallet.sso file originally created? Was the -auto_login_local flag used? If so, you may not be able to copy it like that.

Comment: @hariK Thanks for the response.The file was downloaded from the ADW console.  When I create the secret manually, then it is working fine. However when I am doing it as part of the pipeline, the artifact is not getting uploaded properly. This is how I am trying to copy the file:  writeFile file: "cwallet.sso", text: libraryResource(adw + '/cwallet.sso')